# I need help building a two player turn based simple dice game in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, logic

I relatively new to programming so forgive me for my code. The goal is to create a simple dice game in which there are two players in Javascript. My issue is that I can seem to figure out how to correctly add the sum of the two dice rolls to the score  for each player when the dice is rolled.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Andrews awesome dice game</title>
        <script src="diceGame.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="diceGame.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="gameTitle" class="col-lg-12">The Dice Game</h1>
    <div id="die1" class="dice">0</div>
    <div id="die2" class="dice">0</div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 playerScore">
        <h2>PLAYER 1:</h2>
        <h2 id="player1Score"></h2>
        <h2>PLAYER 2:</h2>
        <h2 id="player2Score"></h2>
    <button onclick="rollDice()" id="rollBtn">Roll Dice</button>
    <h2 id="status" style="clear:left;"></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Heres the Javascipt:

```
//global variables
    //Players
    var player1 = prompt("what is your name, player 1?");
    var player2 = prompt("What is your name, player 2?");
    var rollButton = document.getElementById("rollBtn");
    var win = 50;



function rollDice(){

var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
var die2 = document.getElementById("die2");
var status = document.getElementById("status");
var p1Score = document.getElementById("player1Score");
var p2Score = document.getElementById("player2Score");
var score1 = 0;
var score2 = 0;
var moves = 0;

var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
var d2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
var moves = 1;

var diceTotal = d1 + d2;
die1.innerHTML = d1;
die2.innerHTML = d2;
status.innerHTML = "You rolled "+diceTotal+".";

if (moves == 1) {
    if (d1 == 1 && d2 == 1) { // if both dice equal 1, set the score to equal 0
        diceTotal = 0;
        moves++;
        score1 = score1 + diceTotal;
        p1Score.innerHTML += score1;
        status.innerHTML += " Your score has been reset to zero";
    } else {
        if(d1 == d2) {        //if both dice are the same, double the players score
            diceTotal = diceTotal*2;
            moves++;
            score1 = score1 + diceTotal;
            p1Score.innerHTML += score1;
            status.innerHTML += " Lucky! your total has been doubled to "+(diceTotal)+".";
        } else{
            moves++;
            score1 = score1 + diceTotal;
            p1Score.innerHTML += score1;
            status.innerHTML += " Your Turn "+player2+".";
            console.log(score1);
        }
    }
} else {
    if (d1 == 1 && d2 == 1) { // if both dice equal 1, set the score to equal 0
        diceTotal = 0;
        moves++;
        score2 = score2 + diceTotal;
        p2Score.innerHTML += score2;
        status.innerHTML += player2+" score has been reset to zero";
    } else {
        if(d1 == d2) {        //if both dice are the same, double the players score
            diceTotal = diceTotal*2;
            moves++;
            score2 = score2 + diceTotal;
            p2Score.innerHTML += score2;
            status.innerHTML += " Lucky! your total has been doubled to "+(diceTotal)+".";
        } else{
            moves++;
            score2 = score2 + diceTotal;
            p2Score.innerHTML += score2;
            status.innerHTML += " Your Turn "+player1+"."; 
        }
    }
}
```

}

Forgive me for my sloppy logic. Im still pretty new. Any hints, code suggestions or advice are welcome

Comment: This sounds like a perfect question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Does it work as intended? If so, @DrewGaynor is correct.

Comment: Currently not completely the dice roll works but the scoring and turn system don't work at all

Comment: Then you need to narrow down on the issue and ask a more specific question; as it stands this question is *too broad* to be on-topic. Also, make sure you take a look at the tag wiki for the [tag:code-review] tag ;-)

Comment: If the code is not working yet (as it appears to be the case), please note this would be off-topic for CodeReview.SE.

Comment: Ive narrowed my question. I really just need to know what the best way to build my scoring system would be.

Comment: @Phrancis Agreed- my interpretation of the original revision was that the code was _working_, but OP was looking for general advice, code suggestions, etc. It seems that's not the case.

Comment: It's working. Just not the scoring system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking a guess here, since you don't include the *actual results* the code is producing (good place to start, besides the *expected result*), but these lines here:

```
score1 = score1 + diceTotal;
p1Score.innerHTML += score1;
```

First, `p1Score.innerHTML` is a string. If you add to a string using the `+` operator, `javascript` will **concatenate** the values, not **sum** them, i.e. `"1" + 1 = "11"`

Second, you've already incremented the value of the `score1` variable. Why are you adding the value again?

Try just setting `innerHTML`:

```
p1Score.innerHTML = score1;
```